# How to bind selected radio button value using MVC in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
                     <div class="row mt-4">
                        <div class="col-md-12 correct_answer">
                            <lable>Correct Answer</lable><br /><br />
                            <label class="radio-label">
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsCorrectAnswerOption1, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "radio", id = "IsCorrectAnswerOption1", name = "IsCorrectAnswerOption1"})
                                <span>A</span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-label">
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsCorrectAnswerOption2, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "radio", id = "IsCorrectAnswerOption2", name = "IsCorrectAnswerOption2" })
                                <span>B</span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-label">
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsCorrectAnswerOption3, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "radio", id = "IsCorrectAnswerOption3", name = "IsCorrectAnswerOption3" })
                                <span>C</span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-label">
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsCorrectAnswerOption4, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "radio", id = "IsCorrectAnswerOption4", name = "IsCorrectAnswerOption4" })
                                <span>D</span>
                            </label>
                            <br />
                            <span id="CorrectAnswerError" class="error">Correct Answer is required</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here i have four different radio buttons with different id's and name in that model i have one true value but here i am unable to bind the selected radio value i.e true.

Comment: When you use the helper, it should automatically create appropriate ID, type, and name fields on the output? I don't think you need to set them in the options object.

Comment: i have tried like this  @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsCorrectAnswerOption1, new { @class = "form-control"}) but not working

Comment: you can use javascript for it

Comment: can anyone provide solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using boolean variables for each option you can create an enum and give it as a property in a model. In post method you can directly map selected option by the user by 
MyOptions Property itself.

**Note: Do not change the name attribute of the element.**

```
//Your Model
public class Answer
{
   public Options MyOptions { get; set; }
}

public enum Options
{
  None,
  Option1,
  Option2,
  Option3,
  Option4,

}

//Your Controller

public ActionResult SelectOption()
{
    Answer ans = new Answer();

    return View(ans);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectOption(Answer answer)
{
    var selectedOption = answer.MyOptions;

    return View();
}
```

```html
//Your cshtml page
@model Answer;

@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.MyOptions, Options.Option1) <span>Option 1</span>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.MyOptions, Options.Option2)<span>Option 2</span>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.MyOptions, Options.Option3)<span>Option 3</span>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.MyOptions, Options.Option4)<span>Option 4</span>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

}
```